# How should I store a password used by a service written in .NET

Tags: password-management, .net, service-account

I have a Windows service that accesses a database connection. Since users rarely use Windows authentication, I encrypt the connection string. For development I have the password hard-coded, but I know this is a very bad idea. What is the proper way to store a non-user entered password?

As a side note, I tried storing the password in the Credentials Manager, but this required the service to be run under either the local system account or an administrator account, which some clients do not want to allow.

**Edit**

The main question here is this: What is the best way for a Windows service to store sensitive information?

Comment: Why do users need to connect to the database directly?

Comment: Users are not connecting to the database. The Windows service receives TCP messages and adds the information to the database, where they are consumed by another program.

Comment: Whether or not a user or a windows service connects directly to the database is irrelevant - the question is why there has to be a *direct* connection and not through, say, a service.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm confused. It seems like this is moving the goalpost. If my service uses another service to access the database, then I would need to store a password to access that service and that service would need to store a database password.

Comment: Yes, but it makes a difference whether the database password is stored on the local machine (accessed by a Windows Service) or on a remote server, which offers an API to all local machines. In one scenario, an attacker simply needs access to the machine of any user to access the database directly, whereas in the other, the attacker needs to take over a specific server.

Comment: I don't think I gave enough information originally. My service is a DICOM Receiver that is (usually) installed on the same system as the database. There is only one service installed for a hospital network. Communication access with the receiver is restricted.

Comment: So the employee machines connect to the service in question via the network, and that service is running on the same machine as the database? Just to make sure I understand how the architecture is built.

Comment: Basically. The messages are actually being created and sent by medical devices, so there is no human interaction with the service at all. The service is adding the results of tests to a database which is used by different applications to display test results to medical staff.